# How to merge or add queryParams even if queryParams name is same

Tags: angular, router

At first. the url is http://localhost/kr/shops/search?term=bar

I used this code for adding param

```
this.router.navigate(['/shops/search'], { queryParams: { brand : someValue }, queryParamsHandling: 'merge'});
```

After code is executed, the result of url is http://localhost/kr/shops/search?term=bar&brand=kind

I want to add queryParam infinitely like this.

http://localhost/kr/shops/search?term=bar&brand=kind

http://localhost/kr/shops/search?term=bar&brand=kind&brand=quest

http://localhost/kr/shops/search?term=bar&brand=kind&brand=quest&brand=larlar

but the result of url is always like this

http://localhost/kr/shops/search?term=bar&brand=kind

http://localhost/kr/shops/search?term=bar&brand=quest

http://localhost/kr/shops/search?term=bar&brand=larlar

how to add queryParam infinitely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `brand` property with new value like this:

```
queryParams: { brand : 'kind' }
queryParams: { brand : 'quest' }
queryParams: { brand : 'larlar' }
```

Try this:

```
queryParams: { brand : ['kind'] }
queryParams: { brand : ['kind', 'quest'] }
queryParams: { brand : ['kind', 'quest', 'larlar'] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add query params (using **URLSearchParams**) like this -

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();

params.append('brand', 1);
params.append('brand', 'value2');
```

Refer. from https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11662

Alternate - You can conact string and add as query params like below -

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/?brand=name&brand=bjk')
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/queryparams-multiple?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

PS: I dont know it's valid way to achieve or not but works.

Comment: could you give me some example? I don't know how to use `URLSearchParams()`

Comment: haven't tried yet, but find similar solution many times so thought it should work, have you tried?

Comment: After searching, I found out this feature is not related to angular. that means. no all browsers support it. I have to consider IE11. but IE11 is not support this feature

Comment: I dont think so, https://angular.io/api/http/URLSearchParams, this is of Angular feature and should works for every browser (if working for single one).

Comment: I hope this is not bothering you. But when I log the `params` using `console.log` in my `.ts` file, nothing is printed. but `URLSearchParams {}` lol. the `params` already appended. but it prints just `URLSearchParams {}` I'm just confused. so I started to find another solution. Can you explain how to use this? Thank you for answering. I keep trying to find solution

Comment: yeah actually you are right, it is printing the empty object. Can't you create a string and add in the end of url as queryParams? Just an alternate